# migration android OpenCL on Java Windows

Tags: android, c, windows, opencl

I would like to migrate my android project to windows. But I have no idea how to do it.

1. I want to use Java for video display and capture.
2. use OpenCL and C,C++ for processing.

My problem is that I don't know how to go about compiling and linking on the Windows platform.
I got Jbuider (old version) but I also need GCC for C and GNU for OpenCL I believe.
Can someone help me in the process to follow to achieve my goal.

Thanks in advance

I forgot to say that i use windows7 and openCL 2.0

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                         RESPONSE TO THE QUESTION
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

3 days later and 2 response ;)) and 2 point loss. I found the way to migrate to windows7 and use Opencl 1.2 and compile with cl2.hpp (good).

1. first

donwloand and instal winlibs-x86_64-mcf-seh-gcc-13.1.0-llvm-16.0.2-mingw-w64ucrt-11.0.0-r1.7z form https://winlibs.com/

here is the cpp main file openCL_Windows.cpp

```
#define CL_HPP_ENABLE_EXCEPTIONS
#define CL_HPP_CL_1_2_DEFAULT_BUILD
#define CL_EXT_PREFIX__VERSION_1_1_DEPRECATED
#define CL_API_SUFFIX__VERSION_1_2
#define CL_HPP_MINIMUM_OPENCL_VERSION 100
#define CL_HPP_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION 120
#define CL_HPP_ENABLE_PROGRAM_CONSTRUCTION_FROM_ARRAY_COMPATIBILITY  // used for cl::Program::Sources
#define CL_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION 120

#define ONE_MILLION 1000000LL
#define SPIN_COUNT 512

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <infoGPU.h>
#include <CL/cl2.hpp>

static cl::Context      gContext;
static cl::CommandQueue gQueue;
static cl::Kernel       gIntegraleImg;
static cl::Buffer bufferGray;
static cl::Buffer bufferligne;
static cl::Buffer group;
static cl::Buffer tabtest;
static cl::Buffer intering;

struct my_rect {
    cl_int Lx = 0;
    cl_int Ly = 0;
    cl_int Rx = 0;
    cl_int Ry = 0;
};

struct my_tab {
    cl_uchar tableau[36] = {5,  4,  3,  8,  3,  4,
                            3,  9,  1,  2,  6,  3,
                            9,  6,  0,  5,  7,  5,
                            7,  3,  6,  5,  9,  2,
                            1,  2,  2,  8,  3,  1,
                            2,  5,  4,  8,  3,  6
                            };
};

struct my_bufligne {
    cl_uchar4 bufligne[1024*1024];
};
static my_bufligne buffer;  // entrée
static my_bufligne *buf = &buffer;

cl_uchar Group[1];

char *file_contents(const char *filename, int *length)
{
    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "r");
    void *buffer;

    if (!f) {
        printf("Unable to open %s for reading\n", filename);
        exit(-1);
    }

    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    *length = ftell(f);
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);

    buffer = malloc(*length+1);
    *length = fread(buffer, 1, *length, f);
    fclose(f);
    ((char*)buffer)[*length] = '\0';

    return (char*)buffer;
}

void built_program(cl_program p,void* data)
{

    cl_int err = CL_SUCCESS;
    printf(" 00 built_program() %s", err);
    err = clRetainProgram(p);
    printf(" 0 built_program() %s", err);
    cl_device_id devid[1];
    err = clGetProgramInfo(p,CL_PROGRAM_DEVICES,sizeof(cl_device_id),(void*)devid,NULL);
    printf(" 1 built_program() %s", err);
    char bug[65536];
    err = clGetProgramBuildInfo(p,devid[0],CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG,65536*sizeof(char),bug,NULL);
    printf(" 2 built_program() %s", err);
    err = clReleaseProgram(p);
    printf(" 3 built_program() %s", err);
}

void compileKernels()
{
    // Find OCL devices and compile kernels
    printf(" Start compileKernels \n");
    cl_int err = CL_SUCCESS;

    try {
        printPlatformsAndDevices(); // problem with honnor play

        // utilisé avec ARM mali Honnor Play
        std::vector<cl::Platform> platforms;
        cl::Platform::get(&platforms);
        if (platforms.size() == 0) {
            printf(" Error: no OpenCL platform found \n");
            exit(-1);
        }
        printf(" Platform found \n");


        cl_context_properties properties[] =
        {
            CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM,      (cl_context_properties)(platforms[0])(),0
        };

        gContext = cl::Context(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, properties);

        std::vector<cl::Device> devices;
        devices = gContext.getInfo<CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES>();

        gQueue = cl::CommandQueue(gContext, devices[0], 0, &err);

        printf(" gContext devices gQueue OK \n");

        int src_length = 0;
        const char* src  = file_contents("Kernel.cl",&src_length);
        printf(" file size %d \n",src_length);
        cl::Program program;
        cl::Program::Sources sources(1,std::make_pair(src, src_length) );
        program = cl::Program(gContext, sources);
        program.build(devices,NULL,built_program);
        printf(" program.build finished \n");
        while(program.getBuildInfo<CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_STATUS>(devices[0]) != CL_BUILD_SUCCESS);
        gIntegraleImg       = cl::Kernel(program, "integraleImg", &err);

        printf(" End compileKernels \n");

        bufferGray       = cl::Buffer(gContext, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE  , (1080*1920)*sizeof(cl_uchar4));
        bufferligne        = cl::Buffer(gContext, CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR, (1024*1024)*sizeof(cl_uchar4), buffer.bufligne, NULL);


        // image integral
        group           = cl::Buffer(gContext, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,  1*sizeof(cl_uchar));
        tabtest         = cl::Buffer(gContext, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, 36*sizeof(cl_uchar));
        intering         = cl::Buffer(gContext, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,  6*sizeof(cl_uchar));

        printf(" End create buffer \n");
    }
    catch (cl::Error e) {
            printf(" compileKernels @decode: %s \n",e);
    }
}

void kernel()
{

        struct timeval tv;
        gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
        long long startWhen = (tv.tv_sec * ONE_MILLION) + tv.tv_usec;
        long long endWhen = (tv.tv_sec * ONE_MILLION) + tv.tv_usec;

        // ***************************   TEST IMAGE INTEGRALE   **************************

        my_tab tab;
        gIntegraleImg.setArg(0,tabtest);        // Image Integrale
        gIntegraleImg.setArg(1,intering);       // calcul intermediaire
        gIntegraleImg.setArg(2,tab);            // input table
        gIntegraleImg.setArg(3,6);
        gIntegraleImg.setArg(4,6);
        gIntegraleImg.setArg(5,0);              // sens du calcul X = ligne
        gIntegraleImg.setArg(6,group);          // grouId
        gQueue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(gIntegraleImg, cl::NDRange(0,0), cl::NDRange(6,6), cl::NDRange(6,6));

        gQueue.enqueueReadBuffer(tabtest, CL_TRUE, 0, 36*sizeof(cl_uchar), tab.tableau);

        gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
        endWhen = (tv.tv_sec * ONE_MILLION) + tv.tv_usec;
        printf(" enqueueNDRangeKernel finished in %lld ms \n",(endWhen - startWhen) / 1000);

        gQueue.enqueueReadBuffer(tabtest, CL_TRUE, 0, 36*sizeof(cl_uchar), tab.tableau);

        gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
        endWhen = (tv.tv_sec * ONE_MILLION) + tv.tv_usec;
        printf(" enqueueReadBuffer in %lld ms \n",(endWhen - startWhen) / 1000);

        printf(" tabtest size: %d \n",sizeof(tabtest));
        printf(" tab size: %d \n",sizeof(tab));

        for (int i =0 ; i < sizeof(tab); i++) {
            printf(" tableau ind: %d value: %d \n",i,tab.tableau[i]);
        }

        gQueue.enqueueReadBuffer(intering, CL_TRUE, 0, 6*sizeof(cl_uchar), tab.tableau);
        for (int i =0 ; i < 6 ; i++) {
            printf(" intering ind: %d value: %d \n",i,tab.tableau[i]);
        }

        gQueue.enqueueReadBuffer(group, CL_TRUE, 0, 1*sizeof(cl_uchar), Group);
        printf(" group  value: %d \n",Group[0]);

        gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
        endWhen = (tv.tv_sec * ONE_MILLION) + tv.tv_usec;
        printf(" Lecture tableau finished in %lld ms \n",(endWhen - startWhen) / 1000);

        // ***************************   TEST IMAGE INTEGRALE   **************************

}
int main()
{
    compileKernels();
    kernel();
    // InfoGPU();
    exit(0);
}
```

and the final multi trhead .cpp file for the one how would like to use it ;))

```
#define ONE_MILLION 1000000LL

#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <sys/time.h>

void worker_functionA(void)
{
        struct timeval tv;
        gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
        long long startWhen = (tv.tv_sec * ONE_MILLION) + tv.tv_usec;

        int loop = 0;
        // Loop 10 times
        while(loop < 1000000)
        {
            // Sleep for 1.33 seconds
            //std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1333));
            //std::cout << "Thread A Reporting: " << loop << std::endl;
            loop++;
        }
        gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
        long long endWhen = (tv.tv_sec * ONE_MILLION) + tv.tv_usec;
        std::cout << "Thread A finish " << loop << " in " << (endWhen - startWhen) / 1000 << "ms" <<std::endl;
}

void worker_functionB(void)
{
        struct timeval tv;
        gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
        long long startWhen = (tv.tv_sec * ONE_MILLION) + tv.tv_usec;
        int loop = 0;
        // Loop 10 times
        while(loop < 1000000)
        {
           // Sleep for 2.22 seconds
           //std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2222));
           //std::cout << "Thread B Reporting: " << loop << std::endl;
           loop++;
        }
        gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
        long long endWhen = (tv.tv_sec * ONE_MILLION) + tv.tv_usec;
        std::cout << "Thread B finish " << loop << " in " << (endWhen - startWhen) / 1000 << "ms" <<std::endl;
}

void worker_functionC(void)
{
        struct timeval tv;
        gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
        long long startWhen = (tv.tv_sec * ONE_MILLION) + tv.tv_usec;
        int loop = 0;
        // Loop 10 times
        while(loop < 1000000)
        {
           // Sleep for 2.22 seconds
           //std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2222));
           //std::cout << "Thread B Reporting: " << loop << std::endl;
           loop++;
        }
        gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
        long long endWhen = (tv.tv_sec * ONE_MILLION) + tv.tv_usec;
        std::cout << "Thread C finish " << loop << " in " << (endWhen - startWhen) / 1000 << "ms" <<std::endl;
}

void worker_functionD(void)
{
        struct timeval tv;
        gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
        long long startWhen = (tv.tv_sec * ONE_MILLION) + tv.tv_usec;
        int loop = 0;
        // Loop 10 times
        while(loop < 1000000)
        {
           // Sleep for 2.22 seconds
           //std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2222));
           //std::cout << "Thread B Reporting: " << loop << std::endl;
           loop++;
        }
        gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
        long long endWhen = (tv.tv_sec * ONE_MILLION) + tv.tv_usec;
        std::cout << "Thread D finish " << loop << " in " << (endWhen - startWhen) / 1000 << "ms" <<std::endl;
}

int main()
{
   char result;

        struct timeval tv;
        gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
        long long startWhen = (tv.tv_sec * ONE_MILLION) + tv.tv_usec;

   // Launch two new threads. They will start executing immediately
   std::thread worker_threadA(worker_functionA); 
   std::thread worker_threadB(worker_functionB); 
   std::thread worker_threadC(worker_functionC); 
   std::thread worker_threadD(worker_functionD); 

   // Pause the main thread
   std::cout << "Press a key to finish" << std::endl;
   std::cin >> result;

   // Join up the two worker threads back to the main thread
   worker_threadA.join();
   worker_threadB.join();
   worker_threadC.join();
   worker_threadD.join();

        gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
        long long endWhen = (tv.tv_sec * ONE_MILLION) + tv.tv_usec;
        std::cout << "All Thread finish in " << (endWhen - startWhen) / 1000 << "ms" <<std::endl;
   // Return success
   //return 1;
}
```

3 days of hard work ;)) It is my contribution for minus 2 point ;))

I fotgot the final complitaion on cmd

```
g++ -I. openCL_Windows.cpp OpenCL64.dll -o openCL_Windows.exe
g++ thread.cpp -o thread.exe
```

PS: I had to remove the openCL GUP info because of not enough place. But if i got my 2 point and if someone ask for.

here is InfoGPU output

```
iPlatform 0: NVIDIA CUDA; NVIDIA Corporation
  iDevice 0: deviceTypeToString
CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU; NVIDIA Corporation; GeForce GTX 1060 3GB
getDevice
getPlatformAndDevice
Using iPlatform 0
Using iDevice 0
clDeviceQuery Starting...

1 OpenCL Platforms found

 CL_PLATFORM_NAME:      NVIDIA CUDA
 CL_PLATFORM_VERSION:   OpenCL 1.2 CUDA 10.1.131
 CL_PLATFORM_EXTENSIONS:        cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_lo
cal_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_icd cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_nv_compiler_options cl_nv_device_attribute
_query cl_nv_pragma_unroll cl_nv_d3d9_sharing cl_nv_d3d10_sharing cl_khr_d3d10_sharing cl_nv_d3d11_sharing cl_nv_copy_opts cl_nv_create_buffer
OpenCL Device Info:

 1 devices found supporting OpenCL on: NVIDIA CUDA

 ----------------------------------
 Device GeForce GTX 1060 3GB
 ---------------------------------
 1 CL_PLATFORM_NAME:                    ☻
 1 CL_DEVICE_NAME:                      GeForce GTX 1060 3GB
 1 CL_DEVICE_VENDOR:                    NVIDIA Corporation
  CL_DRIVER_VERSION:                    425.31
  CL_DEVICE_PLATFORM:                   0N§
  CL_DEVICE_TYPE:                       CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU
  CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS:          9
  CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_DIMENSIONS:   3
  CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES:        1024 / 1024 / 64
  CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE:        1024
  CL_DEVICE_MAX_CLOCK_FREQUENCY:        1784 MHz
  CL_DEVICE_ADDRESS_BITS:               64
  CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE:         768 MByte
  CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE:            3072 MByte
  CL_DEVICE_ERROR_CORRECTION_SUPPORT:   no
  CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_TYPE:             local
  CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_SIZE:             48 KByte
  CL_DEVICE_MAX_CONSTANT_BUFFER_SIZE:   64 KByte
  CL_DEVICE_QUEUE_PROPERTIES:           CL_QUEUE_OUT_OF_ORDER_EXEC_MODE_ENABLE
  CL_DEVICE_QUEUE_PROPERTIES:           CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE
  CL_DEVICE_IMAGE_SUPPORT:              1
  CL_DEVICE_MAX_READ_IMAGE_ARGS:        256
  CL_DEVICE_MAX_WRITE_IMAGE_ARGS:       16

  CL_DEVICE_IMAGE <dim>                 2D_MAX_WIDTH     16384
                                        2D_MAX_HEIGHT    32768
                                        3D_MAX_WIDTH     16384
                                        3D_MAX_HEIGHT    16384
                                        3D_MAX_DEPTH     16384
 ----------------------------------
 CL_DEVICE_EXTENSIONS cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_
extended_atomics cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_icd cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_nv_compiler_options cl_nv_device_attribute_query cl_
nv_pragma_unroll cl_nv_d3d9_sharing cl_nv_d3d10_sharing cl_khr_d3d10_sharing cl_nv_d3d11_sharing cl_nv_copy_opts cl_nv_create_buffer
 ---------------------------------
 ----------------------------------
 CL_DEVICE_EXTENSIONS cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_
extended_atomics cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_icd cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_nv_compiler_options cl_nv_device_attribute_query cl_
nv_pragma_unroll cl_nv_d3d9_sharing cl_nv_d3d10_sharing cl_khr_d3d10_sharing cl_nv_d3d11_sharing cl_nv_copy_opts cl_nv_create_buffer
 ---------------------------------
  CL_DEVICE_PREFERRED_VECTOR_WIDTH_<t>  CHAR 1, SHORT 1, INT 1, FLOAT 1, DOUBLE 1


  clPrintDevInfo() FINISHED      ----------------------------------
 CL_DEVICE_EXTENSIONS cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_
extended_atomics cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_icd cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_nv_compiler_options cl_nv_device_attribute_query cl_
nv_pragma_unroll cl_nv_d3d9_sharing cl_nv_d3d10_sharing cl_khr_d3d10_sharing cl_nv_d3d11_sharing cl_nv_copy_opts cl_nv_create_buffer
 ---------------------------------
 ----------------------------------
 CL_DEVICE_EXTENSIONS cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_
extended_atomics cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_icd cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_nv_compiler_options cl_nv_device_attribute_query cl_
nv_pragma_unroll cl_nv_d3d9_sharing cl_nv_d3d10_sharing cl_khr_d3d10_sharing cl_nv_d3d11_sharing cl_nv_copy_opts cl_nv_create_buffer
 ---------------------------------
clDeviceQuery, Platform Name = NVIDIA CUDA, Platform Version = OpenCL 1.2 CUDA 10.1.131, Platform Extension = cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics
cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_byte_addressable_st
ore cl_khr_icd cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_nv_compiler_options cl_nv_device_attribute_query cl_nv_pragma_unroll cl_nv_d3d9_sharing cl_nv_d3d10_sharing
 cl_khr_d3d10_sharing cl_nv_d3d11_sharing cl_nv_copy_opts cl_nv_create_buffer, NumDevs = 1, Device = GeForce GTX 1060 3GB
getInfoOpenCL
Number of Platforms: 1
Platform ID: 0
Platform Name: NVIDIA CUDA
Platform Vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
        Device 0:
                Device Name:    GeForce GTX 1060 3GB
                Device Type:    4
                OpenCL Version: OpenCL 1.2 CUDA
                GPU: 4, CPU: 2, ACC: 8, DEF: 1, CUS: 16
                Device Vendor:  NVIDIA Corporation
                Device Max Compute Units: 9
                Device Global Memory:     3221225472
                Device Max Clock Frequency:     1784
                Device Max Allocateable Memory: 805306368
                Device Local Memory: 49152
                Device Available:    1
                Device Max Work Item Dim:    3
                Device Max Work Work Siz:    1024
```

Best regards ;))

Comment: What device do you have with Windows and Mali?
Can you upgrade Windows to 11 and Windows Subsystem for Android?

Comment: i do not understand the question ?

Comment: 1st question: in one of your answers below you had "So i am going back to ARM GPU and openCL" - I was wondering what Windows device with Mali you had to go back to? But maybe I misunderstood & you're going back to Android.
2nd question: Windows 11 has [windows subsystem for android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/android/wsa/) which might help you avoid porting / large chunks of it.

Comment: 1st I was thinking going back to android hauwei and mali GPU. I do not think that Mali GPU are used on Windows ? I would like to have ARM GPU on PC ;))

Comment: @BenCLark 1st I was thinking going back to android hauwei and mali GPU. I do not think that Mali GPU are used on Windows ? I would like to have ARM GPU on PC ;)). 2nd i do not have windows 11, i still windows 7.

Comment: No commercial Windows PC with Mali that I know of, although I have heard of people installing Windows on Raspberry Pi...

Answer (score 0):

I spend the my sunday to find out about desktop and OpencL.

1. OpenCl were never appreciate with Nvidia or AMD. So you can find OpenCL 1.2 library but not 2.0.
2. OpenCL is more appreciate on smartphonne where ARM and qualcomm use it.
3. If someona want to do GPU computation On desktop they are 2 solution CUDA Nvidia and I do not know for AMD ;)

I find the attitude of Nvidia and AMD and now Apple very selfish. Is like every if processor industry decided to have there own C language and own Processor instruction and compiler. What the mess.

Answer (score 0):

I spend the day trying to instal CUDA on my windows 7 Nvidia GTX 1060.

So, that crashed my graphic card installation, 2 hours to make it work again.

I had the time to look at the CUDA SDK, a gaz factorie of 2.1 G. With no documentation, no simple starting point.

If i compare to Opencl how only need 1 library and few .h and .hpp to run.

So i am going back to ARM GPU and openCL

PS: If some one got a configuration how wotk on windows let me know.